# Object Not Adding in the collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, collections

I have a an Object in the Session namely currentCustomer as follows.

```
public Customer currentCustomer 
        {
            get 
            {
                if (Session["currentCustomer"] == null) return new Customer();
                else 
                   return (Customer)Session["currentCustomer"];
            }
            set 
            {
                Session["currentCustomer"] = value;
            }
        }
```

And also I have an MVC4 action to add the Address into Customer's address List.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CustomerAddressSave()
    {
            Address address  = new Address();
            if (TryUpdateModel<Address>(address))
            {
                UpdateModel<Address>(address);
            }
            currentCustomer.AddressList.Add(address); //Not Adding into the List.
            return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Surprisingly the above code is not adding the Address to the List AddressList;

I have no clue to follow up.

Could anyone had faced the same kind of issue in the past and assist me what went wrong.

Thanks in Advance,
Saravnakumar

Comment: When you do a new Customer() is the AddressList property and the underlying collection object initialized properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get 
{
    if (Session["currentCustomer"] == null) return new Customer();
     else 
     return (Customer)Session["currentCustomer"];
}
```

You want to fix that. That just returns a new Customer object into limbo. You want to assign it to the session

```
get
{
    Customer customer = null;
    if (Session["currentCustomer"] == null)
    {
          customer = new Customer();
          Session["currentCustomer"] = customer;

    }
    else
    {
       customer= (Customer)Session["currentCustomer"];
    }
    return customer;
}
```

It was saving the address before, you just saved it to a new instance each time. The above code should fix it - hopefully.